# Right way to manage time event in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, time

I have to do some time based task(simulation) like,
As the game started:

- After 2 mintues start TrainA.
- After 6 mintues star Train B
- after 12 minutes start Train C and so on

But remember If i want to quickly view the simulation, the timer should be speed able.

Now i am considering two approaches (other approaches are also welcome which is the purpose of the question)

**Each Object (Train) script manage its time by WaitForSeconds:**

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine("MyEvent");
}
     
private IEnumerator MyEvent()
{
    
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(120f); // wait two minutes
    //Launch Train
  
}
```

This kind of script attach to every object that requires action after a certain time:

*Problem:*

1. How do I speed up its time?
2. Maybe Performance intensive. As each script managing its own co-routine(Maybe I am wrong)

**One Global script for Timer:**

```
    function Update ()
    {
    Timer += Time.deltaTime; //Time.deltaTime will increase the value with 1 every second.
    if (timer>= 120){
    //launch train, an so one conditions
   //Or get timer variable in other script and compare time on update 
    }

}
```

Now using the above script I can get the Timer variable in another script and can execute my task based on time in the `update` method.

The question is how do I manage it? Either first way or second way or third way (by you)?
Because I also want to speed up the time too which seems impossible within co-routine once it registers.

Need your help folks!!

Answer (score 5):

You use either of the two ways and simply change [Time.timescale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) if you want to view it faster/slower etc in the example by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd>:

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Toggles the time scale between 1 (normal) and 0.5 (twice as fast)
    // whenever the user hits the Space key.

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (Time.timeScale == 1.0f)
            {
                Time.timeScale = 0.5f;
            }
            else
            {
                Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
            }

            // Also adjust fixed delta time according to timescale
            // The fixed delta time will now be 0.02 frames per real-time second
            Time.fixedDeltaTime = 0.02f * Time.timeScale;
        }
    }
}
```

---

For the Coroutine this works without you having to change anything because [WaitForSeconds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) is affected by the `Time.timescale`:

> The actual time suspended is equal to the given time multiplied by Time.timeScale.

---

`Time.deltaTime` afaik is **not** affacted by the `Time.timescale` so in order to allow faster replay you would have to do

```
private void Update ()
{
    Timer += Time.deltaTime * (1 / Time.timescale); 

    if (timer >= 120)
    {
        //launch train, an so one conditions
        //Or get timer variable in other script and compare time on update 
    }
}
```

---

Whether one `Update` or multiple Coroutines are more performant depends a lot on the specific usecase. Afaik it isn't really noticable until you have like maybe 10.000 Coroutines running (don't nail me on numbers here ;) ).

In your case for only raising one or multiple events it might be better to stick with the one `Update()` method instead and invoke an event or something like that.

**But** - why not simply have one single Coroutine instead of the `Update` at all:

```
public class GlobalTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Delay = 2.0f;
    public UnityEvent onTimerDone;

    // Unity allows to use Start as IEnumerator instead of a void
    private IEnumerator Start()
    {
        yield return new WaitforSeconds(delay);

        onTimerDone.Invoke();
    }
}
```

than you have only one invoked method and can add callbacks to that timer like

```
globalTimerReference.onTimerDone.AddListener(() => {
    Debug.LogFormat("Timer of {0} seconds is done now.", globalTimerReference.Delay);
});
```

or via the inspector (like in a `UI.Button.onClick`).

For multiple events I just came up with a quick and dirty solution so you can simply define multiple events via the inspector and add various callbacks and stuff:

```
public class GlobalTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<UnityEvent> events;
    public List<float> delays;

    private void Start()
    {
        var validPairs = Mathf.Min(events.Count, delays.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < validPairs; i++)
        {
            StartCoroutine(InvokeDelayed(events[i], delays[i]));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator InvokeDelayed(UnityEvent unityEvent, float delay)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

        unityEvent.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Just make sure that for every event there is a delay in the list. In the future you might want to write a proper CustomEditor in order to edit this more beautiful in the inspector.

**Update**

or you can take mine :D

```
public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<EventDelayPair> EventDelayPairs;

    private void Start()
    {
        foreach (var eventDelayPair in EventDelayPairs)
        {
            StartCoroutine(InvokeDelayed(eventDelayPair.unityEvent, eventDelayPair.Delay));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator InvokeDelayed(UnityEvent unityEvent, float delay)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

        unityEvent.Invoke();
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class EventDelayPair
    {
        public UnityEvent unityEvent;
        public float Delay;
    }
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(ExampleScript))]
public class ExampleInspector : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty EventDelayPairs;
    private ReorderableList list;

    private ExampleScript _exampleScript;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _exampleScript = (ExampleScript)target;

        EventDelayPairs = serializedObject.FindProperty("EventDelayPairs");

        list = new ReorderableList(serializedObject, EventDelayPairs)
        {
            draggable = true,
            displayAdd = true,
            displayRemove = true,
            drawHeaderCallback = rect =>
            {
                EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, "DelayedEvents");
            },
            drawElementCallback = (rect, index, sel, act) =>
            {
                var element = EventDelayPairs.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

                var unityEvent = element.FindPropertyRelative("unityEvent");
                var delay = element.FindPropertyRelative("Delay");


                EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), delay);

                rect.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

                EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(unityEvent)), unityEvent);


            },
            elementHeightCallback = index =>
            {
                var element = EventDelayPairs.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

                var unityEvent = element.FindPropertyRelative("unityEvent");

                var height = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(unityEvent) + EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

                return height;
            }
        };
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawScriptField();

        serializedObject.Update();

        list.DoLayoutList();

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    private void DrawScriptField()
    {
        // Disable editing
        EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
        EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Script", MonoScript.FromMonoBehaviour(_exampleScript), typeof(ExampleScript), false);
        EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();

        EditorGUILayout.Space();
    }
}
```

Example

[image]

or with a preview of the delays for debugging

```
public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<EventDelayPair> EventDelayPairs;

    private void Start()
    {
        foreach (var eventDelayPair in EventDelayPairs)
        {
            StartCoroutine(InvokeDelayed(eventDelayPair));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator InvokeDelayed(EventDelayPair pair)
    {
        var timer = pair.Delay;

        do
        {
            timer -= Time.deltaTime * (1 / Time.timeScale);
            pair.Delay = timer;
            yield return null;
        } while (timer > 0);

        pair.Delay = 0;

        pair.unityEvent.Invoke();
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class EventDelayPair
    {
        public UnityEvent unityEvent;
        public float Delay;
    }
}
```

[image]

---

Btw your comment

> //Time.deltaTime will increase the value with 1 every second.

is not formulated correctly. Instead it should be:

> `Time.deltaTime` will increase the value every frame about the time passed in seconds since the last frame was rendered.

---

**EDIT - Reduce delays afterwards**

I understood from the question that you wanted to `speed up` the entire playback.

From the comments I learned now that instead you wanted to rather reduce the delay afterwards. So you can't use `Time.timescale`.

For this you can use the second example a bit altered:

```
[Serializable]
public class EventDelayPair
{
    public UnityEvent unityEvent;
    public float Delay;
    // add a time multiplicator for each delay with default 1
    public float TimeMultiplicator = 1.0f;
}
```

**Note**: You'll have to also add it to the EditorScript if you use it - I leave this as your homework ;)

```
private IEnumerator InvokeDelayed(EventDelayPair pair)
{
    var timer = pair.Delay;

    do
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime * pair.TimeMultiplicator;
        pair.Delay = timer;
        yield return null;
    } while (timer > 0);

    pair.Delay = 0;

    pair.unityEvent.Invoke();
}
```

so you can in the Inspector or also by script

```
exampleScriptReference.EventDelayPairs[0].TimeMultiplicator = 2;
```

reduce the Delay faster.

You might also want to add an overall multiplicator like

```
// Again you have to add it to the inspector if you use it
public float overallMultiplicator = 1.0f;

//...
    timer -= Time.deltaTime * pair.TimeMultiplicator * overallMultiplicator;
```

Comment: Thanks @derHugo your code has revealed so many positives things for me. Thanks but

Comment: I can control the speed of time using the co-routine WaitForSeconds.

Comment: and if i tried to mess with timeScale then surely it will effect all over the project.

Comment: `and if i tried to mess with timeScale then surely it will effect all over the project.`oh your question sounded like you want to just speed up everything ... I wouldn't say `speed up`. What you try to archive is actually `reduce the delay`. See my update at the bottom section!

Answer (score 1):

For a project where time management is as crucial as this, I would probably opt for the second method you propose as that will offer far more control over the simulation. You could create a class or struct (Let's call it `EventData`)that stores the required info for each event (The event to call, time before event occurs, etc.) and then store them in a list inside your time manager. Each frame you can then iterate through the list and subtract the proper amount of time from each item in the list, and when an event's time is <= 0, call the event, then remove it from the list. This way you can easily add or remove items from the manager without having to worry about the state of the individual objects that start the timers changing and potentially messing up timing.

One thing I want to add is that derHugo's statement that "`Time.deltaTime` afaik is not affacted by the `Time.timescale`" is entirely inaccurate. `Time.deltaTime` is very much affected by `Time.timescale`, which is why `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` exists. Multiplying `Time.deltaTime` by (1 / `Time.timeScale`) as suggested will effectively undo the scaling Unity automatically applies, making it equivalent to `Time.unscaledDeltaTime`. Not to mention that if `Time.timeScale` were set to 0 (Which is a common way of implementing pausing) then you'd end up with a divide by zero situation with that code. (Furthermore, if `Time.deltaTime` **wasn't** scaled as was stated, multiplying it by the inverse of `Time.timeScale` would scale it in *reverse*, such that increasing the time scale would slow things down and decreasing it would speed things up). That said it can still be useful to give objects individual time scales. For example, you could add a `timeScale` variable to `EventData` and then use that to make individual trains run at different simulation speeds. When updating the remaining time variable for each `EventData` you could do something like this pseudo code:

```
timedEvents[i].remainingTime -= Time.deltaTime * timedEvents[i].timeScale
```

This code will take both `Time.timeScale` and `EventData.timeScale` into account (Since Time.deltaTime is automatically scaled by `Time.timeScale`).